# Make a child element fill the min-width of the parent

Tags: css

I have a table nested in a div. The div has a min width. I want the table to stretch to the min width of the div and beyond that if needed.

html:

```
<div class="container">
    <table class="content">
        <tr>
          <td>not much here</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

css:

```
.container {
    min-width: 15em;
    background-color: pink;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 2px;
}

.content td {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

I want the td to fill the container. But if the content was longer then the container should stretch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply `width:100%` for your table.

```
.content{width:100%;}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/afhx9du7/)

Comment: Thanks. I thought I had tried that. There must be something peculiar about the real code. I'll examine it further.